# Transforming list of periods into a list of dates in c#

Tags: c#, linq, generic-list

I have a c# list containing periods using cDates class.

```
public class cDates
{
     public Date PeriodStart {get;set;}
     public Date PeriodEnd {get;set;}
}


2014/01/01 - 2014/04/30
2014/05/01 - 2014/07/31
2014/08/01 - 2014/09/30
```

Is it possible to get a list of dates containing all dates in existing periods, something like List.

```
public class cSingleDate
{
             public Date SingleDate {get;set;}
}

    2014/01/01
    2014/01/02
    2014/01/03
    ...
    2014/09/30
```

I tried to find a solution using loops, but want to find out is there a cleaner solution. Maybe a Linq solution?

Comment: What is `Dates` type?

Comment: Don't prefix your classes with "c": [do not use Hungarian notation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @BCdotNET i am doing this only for classes. Class will always be class, so I dont see any harm here.

Comment: @mko have you already solved it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LINQ for that:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestPeriods()
{
    var periods = new[]
                    {
                        new Period(new DateTime(2014, 01, 01), new DateTime(2014, 04, 30)),
                        new Period(new DateTime(2014, 05, 01), new DateTime(2014, 07, 31)),
                        new Period(new DateTime(2014, 08, 01), new DateTime(2014, 09, 30)),
                    };

    var days = from period in periods
                let numberOfDays = (period.LastDay - period.FirstDay).Days + 1
                from day in Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfDays)
                select period.FirstDay.AddDays(day);

    var distinctDays = days.Distinct().ToArray();

    distinctDays.Should().Contain(new DateTime(2014, 01, 01));
    distinctDays.Should().Contain(new DateTime(2014, 02, 01));
    distinctDays.Should().Contain(new DateTime(2014, 04, 30));
    distinctDays.Should().NotContain(new DateTime(2014, 10, 01));
}

public class Period
{
        public Period(DateTime firstDay, DateTime lastDay)
        {
            this.FirstDay = firstDay;
            this.LastDay = lastDay;
        }

        public DateTime FirstDay {get;set;}
        public DateTime LastDay {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just loop through dates, and add one day to `PeriodStart` as long as it's less than or equal to `PeriodEnd`:

```
var dates = new List<cSingleDate>();
foreach(var date in cDates)
{ 
    while(date.PeriodStart <= date.PeriodEnd)
    { 
        dates.Add(new cSingleDate { SingleDate = date.PeriodStart });
        date.PeriodStart = date.PeriodStart.AddDays(1);
    }
}
```

If you don't wanna change `cDates` just use a temporary variable to store `PeriodStart`.

Comment: this is pretty much the same i got. I was looking for a more of a linq solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are two easy ways to transform the dates from the `Period` class into a single list of dates. You can either extend the `Period` class to give you the dates and use linq to flatten it or you read both properties with linq. If the `SingleDate` class really only stores the date and nothing else and if it does not provide any additional functionality you may consider to just extract the dates.

```
// Test data.
var periods = new[]
{
    new Period(new DateTime(2014, 01, 01), new DateTime(2014, 04, 30)),
    new Period(new DateTime(2014, 05, 01), new DateTime(2014, 07, 31)),
    new Period(new DateTime(2014, 08, 01), new DateTime(2014, 09, 30)),
};
```

If you can make the `Period` class to implement `IEnumerable<DateTime>` interface and thus flatten the dates for you then a simple `SelectMany` can be used:

```
var result1 =
    periods
    // The Period class will enumerate the dates for SelectMany:
    .SelectMany(x => x)
    // Uncomment this line if you want to encapsulate the date.
    //.Select(x => new SingleDate() { Date = x })    
    .ToList();
```

Otherwise you need to flatten the `Period` dates inside the `SelectMany`:

```
var resul2 =
    periods
    // Here SelectMany has to enumerate the dates:
    .SelectMany(x => new[] 
    {
        x.PeriodStart, 
        x.PeriodEnd 
    })
    // Uncomment this line if you want to encapsulate the date.
    //.Select(x => new SingleDate() { Date = x })
    .ToList();
```

`Period`-class that implements the `IEnumerable<DateTime>` interface to enumerate the dates:

```
public class Period : IEnumerable<DateTime>
{
    public Period(DateTime firstDay, DateTime lastDay)
    {
        this.PeriodStart = firstDay;
        this.PeriodEnd = lastDay;
    }

    public DateTime PeriodStart { get; set; }

    public DateTime PeriodEnd { get; set; }

    public IEnumerator<DateTime> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return PeriodStart;
        yield return PeriodEnd;
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

`SingleDate`-class without changes (you don't need it if it does not provide any additional functionality):

```
public class SingleDate
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```